# Dynamic Height Tailwind CSS [Scroll]

Tags: tailwind-css

have been working on this for a long time, and still stuck. I had to ask for help at last.
https://play.tailwindcss.com/daNoTjnFDQ So here I want the div at line 3 to scroll and not the parent one. Have spent hours on this and couldn't figure out. Seems like the div needs some height but how can it be dynamic. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You will need to add `max-h-** overflow-y-scroll` to the div.

```
  <main class="bg-gray-100 rounded-tl-3xl pl-8 h-screen">
    <div class="mx-auto py-8 pr-8 max-h-96 overflow-y-scroll bg-red-100">
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much. In my case, i have a popup dropdown when search input change.

```
<div class="h-fit overflow-hidden">
<div class="overflow-y-auto scrollbar w-full max-h-96">
Load conten here
</div>
</div>
```